# Square Head Tuning Hammer size

Tags: piano, tuning

I have a Year 1928 made Clayton upright piano. May I know what size of tuning hammer should I buy. I bought one square head tuning hammer but it is too big for the pin. Also, any idea where I can find the right size tuning hammer. Thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: For what they cost, it's most likely worth having a selection (3 or 4), as with an older piano, some of the pins may not fit one hammer too well - so a better fit will be available.